# Bash script getting automatically deleted from Ubuntu 12.04 Server?

Tags: bash, cron, ubuntu-12.04

I'm running a bash script on an ubuntu 12.04 through cron. The script works fine for a few weeks (runs daily backups of websites, mysql databases, and copies to Amazon S3).

However, twice now I've noticed that backups stopped happening. Both times the backup script (backupscript.sh) located in my home folder was no longer there. No one else has access to this server, so nothing was manually changed on the server and no one deleted the file by mistake.

The cron job (nano /etc/crontab) still references this script, but the script itself disappears.

What could cause this to happen? Does Ubuntu delete the script if it runs into some sort of error?

Comment: Does your cron script have a "rm ..." command anywhere in it? Its likely overwriting the cron script itself.

Comment: Did you check the script for obvious things like `rm $0`?

Comment: Thanks guys... that was the problem. I was running a RM command and my carelessness in the directory choices I made caused the backup script to remove itself. I should have seen that... so thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Glad it's solved. I've made a full answer out of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Files disappearing on linux server](http://serverfault.com/questions/304121/files-disappearing-on-linux-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the script for obvious things like `rm $0`? It sounds like the backup script is deleting itself.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could have also set the file as immutable too?

Chattr + i script.sh